# CakePHP saving data in multiple tables

Tags: cakephp

I have shop struct like

1: `Shop` has many `Categories`

2: `Categories` have 1 to many `Sizes` and `Products`

3:  Each `product` belongs to exactly one `Category`

4: As `Sizes` belongs to `Categories` so each `product` belonging to a `category` will have same sizes.

**Now my problem is in Product add form.**

I have form the contains product's input fields and a selectbox to select the `Category`.

As soon as I select a category, an Ajax request will be created, which return `sizes` as inputbox assigned to the selected category. The input boxes will be used to enter the price
for each size of the product. (As the input fields will be generated in Ajax, how may i use the form helper?)

Now I want that on clicking the save button, the product information should be stored in product table, and the prices should be saved in

`Product_Prices` table which contains `product_id, size_id, price` columns.

How should i name my inputboxs? and how should i call the save method so that the informations are properly saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To save one-size**

```
//$this->Form->create('Product');
$this->Form->input('category_id');
```

**To save many-size**

```
//$this->Form->create('Shop');

$this->Form->input('category_id');
```

or use checkbox instead list

```
$this->Form->input('category_id', array('multiple' => 'checkbox'));
```

---

If you want to save property of another model together with you main model you add model name (alias) as prefix and use `saveAssociated()` or `saveAll()`.

```
echo $this->Form->input('ProductPrice.price');
```

see: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array